How to check die temperatures on an Apple Silicon Mac?
On a Mac Studio M2 Max I run:
% sudo powermetrics --samplers smc | grep -i "CPU die temperature"
Password:
powermetrics: unrecognized sampler: smc

It works on an Intel i9 MacBook Pro but not on a modern Mac. Is there no need for the tool anymore?
What about corner cases?

"No need for the tool anymore?" -- There's almost never a need to check the temperatures on an M chip. It's fine.

Thermal loading and power measurements of Apple silicon processor classes are generally what people need if you used to watch peak core temperatures. Things are quite a bit different on Apple core frequency and efficiency based task scheduling vs adapting to the Intel way of primarily adopting thermal throttling. Drop me a comment if you need extra details I didn’t cover

I used to run Temparature Gauge Pro on earlier models, but since the transition to Apple Silicon I really never felt any need for it, those things are just so efficient... Now I've never really pushed the envelope, so maybe if you do such info is still useful.

Do you need to have the info in any way (CLI or UI) or do you specifically need CLI (or API)?

There's almost never a need to check the temps on any personal computer. People who want to measure fan speeds, temperatures, etc. on personal computers are generally doing so for bragging rights or personal amusement, not because it's crucial information they can't do without.

Those CPU by CPU breakdown are not provided on Apple Silicon and now that we have experience on M1 through M3 and see M4 hitting people's hands, the redesign to focus on thermal pressure values of Nominal, Fair, Serious, or Critical is working well for measuring temperature.  The efficiency-first design of macOS and Apple Silicon have moved away from running a CPU at the extreme heat and instead made power savings and efficient execution the norm.

Since there are 50 or more core processing units on the M2 Max (and no hardware report for each of the 50 parts), you may need to also focus QOS measurements of specific workloads and CPU frequency distributions if you don't get the details needed from overall thermal state of the unified ANE + RAM + GPU + CPU integrated package.
sudo powermetrics -s thermal -n 1

The powermetrics tool also can give you a split between CPU and GPU if that becomes relevant to your measurement needs.
sudo powermetrics -s cpu_power,gpu_power,ane_power -n 1


drop the -n 1 for ongoing samples
the manual page and help are quite helpful

Using only the above two commands has been useful and relevant for me since M1 to the M3 days and hopefully scales well to M4 (and Pro / Ultra / Max models) and future generations of the hardware lineup.

You can use Hot. This will show more metrics than anyone sensibly needs... all your corner cases.
There are differences between Intel & Apple metrics:

Differences between the Intel and Apple Silicon versions
On an Intel machine, Hot will display the CPU temperature, CPU speed limit (throttling), scheduler limit and number of available CPUs.
By default, the menu bar text will be colorized in orange if the CPU speed limit falls below 60%.
On Apple Silicon, these informations are not available.
Along with the CPU temperature, Hot will display the system's thermal pressure.
The menu bar text will be colorized in orange if the pressure is not nominal.


Macs Fan Control  - shows all temperature sensors with the free version.
